# VB.net: Date without time

Tags: vb.net, formatting

How do you format the date time to just date?

For example, this is what I retrieved from the database: 12/31/2008 12:00:00 AM, but I just want to show the date and no time.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Either use one of the [standard date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) which only specifies the date (e.g. "D" or "d"), or a [custom date and time format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) which only uses the date parts (e.g. "yyyy/MM/dd").

Comment: for example: DateTime.Now.ToString("d")

Comment: This works if you want a string result.  If you want a date result, see madcolor's response below.  I mean I guess you could just cast the string back to a date, but it's an extra step.

Comment: @Aaron: What do you think `FormatDateTime` (in madcolor's answer) returns? The OP wants a string - that's what "format" means, and that's what both my result and `FormatDateTime` give. The difference is that using `ToString` is a more .NET-idiomatic approach, which doesn't require Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.

Answer (score 37):

FormatDateTime(Now, DateFormat.ShortDate)

Comment: No clue why this doesn't have more upvotes.  Maybe people don't realize you can replace the Now with any date?  Either way, good on you.  upvoted.

Answer (score 14):

I almost always use the standard formating ShortDateString, because I want the user to be in control of the actual output of the date.

### **Code**

```
   Dim d As DateTime = Now
   Debug.WriteLine(d.ToLongDateString)
   Debug.WriteLine(d.ToShortDateString)
   Debug.WriteLine(d.ToString("d"))
   Debug.WriteLine(d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

### **Results**

```
Wednesday, December 10, 2008
12/10/2008
12/10/2008
2008-12-10
```

Note that these results will vary depending on the culture settings on your computer.

Answer (score 5):

Format datetime to short date string and convert back to date

```
CDate(YourDate.ToString("d"))
```

Or use short date string

```
CDate(YourDate.ToShortDateString)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, if for some reason you don't like any of the more sensible answers, just discard everything to the right of (and including) the space.

Comment: Could it be possible that a user could set up a space as their date separation character? If so then your suggestion would fail - unlikely as it might be.

Comment: Not familiar enough with VB.Net to say.  Other frameworks & databases I've used always return the date in the same format regardless of what the OS settings are, and it's up to the app to translate.