# Eliminate the time in date in Listview

Tags: mysql, vb.net, listview

```
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.Open()
        End If
        Dim query As String = "select * from `member` ORDER BY  `membname` "
        adptr = New MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        adptr.Fill(dt)
        lstmem.Items.Clear()
        For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            With lstmem
                .Items.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(1).ToString)
                With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                    .Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(2).ToString)
                    .Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(3).ToString)
                    .Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(4).ToString)
                    .Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(5).ToString)
                    .Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(6).ToString)
                    .Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(7).ToString)
                    .Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(8).ToString)

                End With
            End With
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

that is my code in my listview to view the data. item 4 is a date value.. and it shows date and time.. how can i eliminate the time in listview and shows only the date?

Comment: What is the data type of the date column in the db? Define "short date."

Comment: in mysql my date named as membdate and data type is Date

Answer (score 0):

[VB.net: Date without time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356972/vb-net-date-without-time)
This is an answer already posted on here for the help i think you may be looking for.

Comment: how will i reconstruct my code? i dont know how to start using the idea you have .

Comment: Going further on what @JRD said above I'm not sure it is formatted as Date type [MySQL Reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html) this shows the data type Date as being YYYY-MM-DD.  Also the first part of your question isn't showing up as code.  Just adding 4 spaces to the start of the question should fix this.

Comment: in my Mysql the data type is "DATE" and it shows 2015-01-02 (yyyy-mm-dd) but in my listview in vb it shows 2/1/2015 with a time. and i want to format it in yyyy-mm-dd . without the time

Comment: have you tried chnaging the `.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(4).ToString)` to `.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(4).ToString("your format"))`